# apacite: Capitalize "von" author prefix at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, apa-style

I am using `apacite` to build my bibliography.

In this bibliography, there is one author with a German "von" prefix (von Bühlow).

When using `\citeA`, the author I am getting "von Bühlow", which is the desired behavior. 
However, when starting a sentence with the author name, it should be capitalized (Von Bühlow).

Is there an easy way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: If you use the `natbibapa` option, you can use `natbib` citation commands which offer capitalized versions of the citation commands, `\Citet`.  Other than that, I don't think there's a simple solution using the "classic" `apacite` commands.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! That would mean that I have to change all the \cite and \citeA commands to the corresponding natbib commands, right?

Comment: I'm not sure, since I don't use the package.  You could try a mixture to see what happens.  Also the syntax of the two sets of commands is different, so you can't just replace the `\citeA` with its `natbib` equivalent if you are using any of the optional arguments which classic `apacite` puts in `<>` but `natbib` puts in `[ ]`.

Comment: Mixing the two does not work; the 'apacite' commands do not work anymore, once the 'natbibapa' option is used. Thank you for pointing out the difference in syntax; this will cause some extra work..

Comment: In German, the last name is Bühlow, the "von" isn't part of the last name. So we talk about ["Bismark"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_von_Bismarck) (complete translated name "Otto Eduard Leopold, Prince of Bismarck, Duke of Lauenburg", also known as "Otto von Bismark"), rarely about "von Bismark".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic `apacite` commands have no way of dealing with this case.  Instead you should use the `natbibapa` option of the package, and use the `natbib` citation commands which provide uppercase initial citation commands such as `\Citet` which do what you need.

From the `apacite` documentation, p.10:

> `natbib` provides a set of commands (e.g., `\Citet`) that capitalize the first letter of a citation. This can be used when a citation, of which the first author’s name starts with a lowercase letter, starts a sentence (APA manual, p. 101). This behavior would be very hard to reproduce with the `apaciteclassic` commands.